# JSON cross domain without a jsonp server

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, firefox-os

I'm making a FireFoxOS **packaged** app.
I want to get a library from a public json-api server, but the server that offers the services does not change the json to jsonp (with ?callback or ?jsonp still return just a json) is there a workaround on the client side?
Im using jquery or zepto and backbone
My code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: apiMangaeden[0],
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: 'data',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('It works')
    }
});
```

Comment: The server must support JSONP to supply a JSONP response. If its publicly accessible why do you want to use JSONP?

Comment: @porfuse because the client browsser dnot lauch the ajax.success function, it get the json but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not your HTTP server and it doesn't support CORS or JSONP, you need to request the cross-site request permission (*systemXHR permission*) and set *"type": "privileged"* in your *manifest.webapp*:

https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/communications/manifest.webapp#L81

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/Packaged_apps#Types_of_packaged_apps

and set the *mozSystem* property on the XHR object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Non-standard_properties

https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/communications/contacts/js/fb/fb_query.js#L37

On jquery >= 1.5.1 you should be able to set it using the *xhrFields* setting on $.ajax:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: apiMangaeden[0],
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'data',
  xhrFields: {
    mozSystem: true
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log('It works')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you CORS Proxy
CORS Proxy allows javascript code on your site to access resources on other domains that would normally be blocked due to the same-origin policy.

http://www.corsproxy.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need the `systemXHR` permission:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/App_permissions